# What type of scale is appropriate in this situation

Tags: java, math

Please forgive if this an inappropriate question or place to ask but I could do with some help figuring out an appropriate scale to use for a problem.

The platform is Java but it's more of a general programming/maths question.

I'm not looking for somebody to solve the problem for me but a pointer in the right area to explore as my experience with this type of problem is limited.

Given a sample set of percentages and associated quantities what type of scale would I use to calculate a quantity for a given percentage?

```
25% = 8
50% = 10
75% = 12
```

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What do you mean by "scale"?  This is a straightforward arithmetic question and "scale" does not seem to apply here.  The question as asked has no Java component.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a better fit on http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this

```
25% = 8
50% = 10
75% = 12
```

looks like a linear equation for

```
25% = 6 + 8 * 25% = 8
50% = 6 + 8 * 50% = 10
75% = 6 + 8 * 75% = 12
```

in java can be defined as:

```
double total = 6 + 8 * procent / 100;
```

where procent should be a parameter to the method **between 0 and 100**

Comment: Thank you that works. Can you advise how you came to this conclusion so I can research further please?

Comment: hey @MathsDummy, you need to check the step increasing by every % change, meaning that your value is changing at a rate of 2 points every 25%....